# How can I edit the Text Size in a Python Pretty Print Table html string?

Tags: python, html, prettytable

Suppose I have a sample table:

```
myTable = PrettyTable([])
myTable.add_column("X", [2])
myTable.add_column("Y", [1])
myTable.get_html_string()
```

How would I edit the font size in the table from the HTML string?

Comment: you can always append own `CSS` to generated `HTML` to change any element in HTML. And this is standard method on all web pages.

Comment: if you want to modify only some elements in row or column then maybe first create list/array with HTML elements and later convert it with `PrettyTable` - ie. `["<bold>Hello</bold>", "World"]` instead of `["Hello", "World"]`

Comment: first you should see documetation: [setting html attributes](https://github.com/jazzband/prettytable#setting-html-attributes). Example adds some `ID`, `CLASS` which you can use in `CSS` to modify elements. Eventually should work to add `STYLE` to change elements directly. Shortly different solutions may need different methods. But always it needs to learn `CSS`